itext7 pdf google Hindi font issue
The provided code aims to create a PDF document using iText7 library in Kotlin, but there seems to be an issue related to using the Google Hindi Indic font.
fun createPdf(context: Context) {
    // Create a new PDF document using itext7


    try {


        val pdfFile = File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "pdf")


        if (!pdfFile.exists()) {
            pdfFile.mkdirs()
        }

        //add custom font


        val font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(
            "assets/martel_semibold.ttf",
            PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H
        )


        val outputFile = File(pdfFile,"example.pdf")
        val writer = PdfWriter(outputFile)
        val pdf = PdfDocument(writer)
        pdf.defaultPageSize = PageSize.A4
        val document = Document(pdf)

        document.setFont(font)
        

        document.add(Paragraph("आपका नाम क्या है ?"))
        document.close()
        println("PDF created: ${outputFile.absolutePath}")
        
        Toast.makeText(context, "PDF created: ${outputFile.absolutePath}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show()

    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Toast.makeText(context, e.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}

This condensed version retains the essential parts of the function:

It creates a PDF document with a question in Hindi.

It attempts to use a custom font ("martel_semibold.ttf").

If successful, it shows a toast message with the path to the created PDF.

If an exception occurs during the process, it shows a toast message with the error




Which version of iText core and pdfCaligraph do you use?

So what is the "issue" that a font seems to be causing? Is the PDF corrupt? Does PDF creation fail with an exception?
